# Get Substring directory path not include first folder name in substring

Tags: c#

Basically I want to sub-string directory path for example **path is "server/student/personal/contact"** 
I want to path like "/student/personal/contact". That's mean first folder name I don't want to in 
in path. Every time this path is change by project requirement so how to **remove first folder name** 
from string path.

problem that here in string path first Folder name not same name every time So please help for this **how to remove first folder name from string path**

Comment: Your question is unreadable, I did understand nothing! If you need an answer, I suggest you to rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string strp = "server/student/personal/contact";
strp = strp.Substring(strp.IndexOf("/"));
```

Output:

```
/student/personal/contact
```

Comment: What if it is `"server\student\personal\contact"`?

Answer (score 0):

I usually write something like this

```
string example = "server/student/personal/contact";
var paths = example.Split('/').ToList();
if (paths.Any())
{
    paths.RemoveAt(0);
}
string result = string.Join("/", paths);
```

or you can:

```
string example = "server/student/personal/contact";
var pos = example.IndexOf("/", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
if (pos > 0)
{
    example = example.Substring(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this :

```
string path = "server/student/personal/contact";
//IndexOf() gives you the first occurrence of the character.
int firstSlash=path.IndexOf('/');
string modifiedPath = path.Substring(firstSlash);
```